# Laravel 5.6 Reoccuring Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have an error that occurs no matter what the actual error is within Laravel 5.6 It just keeps saying `Could not find resource 'views/layouts.html.php' in any resource paths.(searched: /var/www/{domain}/vendor/filp/whoops/src/Whoops/Handler/../Resources)` for everything that causes an error and doesn't display the full debug page that Laravel usually displays. I'm not sure what caused this or what I could do to fix it besides reinstalling Laravel, which I'd highly prefer not to do. Does anybody have any ideas what file I might be missing or what might be causing this?

Image of full error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu3CX.jpg

Comment: A quick google search of the error gave me this: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4630 and https://laravel.io/forum/06-10-2014-whoops-is-throwing-an-error

Comment: Neither of these worked since both solutions are outdated. I've updated my question to include a screenshot of the full error. The only thing I did was remove the site name for privacy reasons via Inspect Element.

Answer (score -1):

why you use `layout.html.php`. Laravel has a template engine blade. you can use `layout.blade.php`

You Need to use `views.layout`. example:

```
   return view('views.layout');
```

But note there are views is a folder name. if you create a folder under views folder then you can call views folder. Laravel default views folder is `views` don't need to call on `return path`.

Comment: `view('views.layout'); ` should be `view('layout');` because views is the default folder so we don't write default folder name

Comment: If you read the link I posted on the comment you will know that OP is not the one that created that view, it's part of whoops in Laravel.