# Laravel Query Builder Issue

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to make it so that the items pulled from the database are only from the current month, however when I do this using various methods it throws an error (which I can't debug due to a the issue mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50596309/laravel-5-6-reoccuring-error)). In the code below if I just simply paginate the full results it works fine, but when I start to use query builder methods it gives an error, does anybody have any idea why this error is occurring?

```
public function index()
{
//        $trades=Trade::paginate(10);

    $currentMonth = date('m');
    $trades = DB::table('trades')->whereMonth('date', $currentMonth)->paginate(10);

//        dd($trades);

    $pastwinners=Winner::paginate(10);
    return view('raffle', compact('pastwinners'), compact('trades'));
}
```

As you can see above the $pastwinners variable and the first $trades variable provide the proper values, but when I'm trying to select only the ones from this month (using the 'date' field) it seems to break.

Comment: Does `Trade::` instead of `DB::table('trades')->` work? Does `->get()` instead of `->paginate(10)` work?

Comment: Yea, the top line that is commented out works fine, but I want to be able to select only the items from the current month.

Comment: Does `Trade::whereMonth('date', $currentMonth)->get();` work? What's the result of `dd(Trade::whereMonth('date', $currentMonth)->toSql());`?

Comment: It works with a dd, but breaks when I render the view, I need to be able to paginate the results.


The results from the second line was `select * from 'trades' where month('date') = ?`

Comment: Can you post the view?

Comment: The only thing that breaks it is the `{{ $trades->links() }}` part. I've only used pagination with the method for it, how would I go about limiting it by 10 rows per page?

Comment: Does `$trades->links()` work in the controller? Or does it at least give you a better error message?

Comment: I managed to get it by just replacing get with paginate. Thanks for your help Jonas!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. And if you want to paginate your results, do not forget to add pagination links to your view. Also do not forget the import `Carbon` in your controller class.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination

```
    public function index()
    {
        $trades = Trade::whereMonth('date' , Carbon::today()->month)->paginate();

        $pastwinners = Winner::all();

        return view('raffle', compact('pastwinners', 'trades');
    }
```

Comment: I need to be able to paginate the results.

Comment: Please see my edited answer and let me know if it works.